# Do tables share partitions ("low level rows") in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql3

Let's say I have two tables (column families) defined through CQL.

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    pk    uuid,
    cka   int,
    val   text,
    PRIMARY KEY (pk, cka)
);

CREATE TABLE b (
    pk    uuid,
    ckb   text,
    val1  boolean,
    val2  decimal,
    PRIMARY KEY (pk, ckb)
);
```

If I now insert a row into each table with the same partition key:

```
INSERT INTO a (pk, cka, val)
     VALUES ('f47ac10b-58cc-4372-a567-0e02b2a3d379', 5, 'hi');

INSERT INTO b (pk, ckb, val1, val2)
     VALUES ('f47ac10b-58cc-4372-a567-0e02b2a3d379', 'x', 'hello', 'hey');
```

Will there now be 1 or 2 rows on the storage level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be 2.

Data in Cassandra is written into "memtables", and then flushed to "SSTables" on-disk. Both memtables and SSTables are maintained *on a per-column family basis*, so rows in different column families (tables) will always create distinct rows at the storage level.

See http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/dml/about_writes

> Cassandra writes are first written to a commit log (for durability),
>   and then to an in-memory table structure called a memtable. A write is
>   successful once it is written to the commit log and memory, so there
>   is very minimal disk I/O at the time of write. Writes are batched in
>   memory and periodically written to disk to a persistent table
>   structure called an SSTable (sorted string table). Memtables and
>   SSTables are maintained per column family. Memtables are organized in
>   sorted order by row key and flushed to SSTables sequentially (no
>   random seeking as in relational databases).